# How to show longer traces in Rails TestCases

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, unit-testing

Is there a config variable to set, or some other way to get Rails `ActiveSupport::TestCase` to show **more than one** trace line? It is really hard to debug otherwise.

Example:

```
ERROR test_something (0.73s) 
      SystemStackError: stack level too deep
      /Users/mario/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.0.9/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:153
```

Comment: Can you show an example?

Comment: I hate begging for bounties, but if you do not award it _(to anyone, not necessarily me)_ it will be wasted. It would be sad, wouldn't it? ;-)

Comment: Changed to minitest in meantime, where defining $DEBUG does the magic. No tested with UnitTest though.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

See whether you haven't a file `config/initializers/backtrace_silencers.rb`

It says:

```
# You can also remove all the silencers if you're trying to debug
# a problem that might stem from framework code.
Rails.backtrace_cleaner.remove_silencers!
```

You can also call `remove_filters!` if the first was not enough, but filters only make the paths shorter, while silencers do remove some lines from the backtrace.

You may find the source code in `railties/lib/rails/backtrace_cleaner.rb` and `activesupport/lib/active_support/backtrace_cleaner.rb` useful.

Comment: Wow, seems to be the solution! Totally forgot this initializer.

Answer (score 2):

You can customize Minitest stack traces like this for example:

```
class MyBacktraceFilter
  def filter bt
    bt.dup.reject{|x| not x.to_s =~ /#{::Rails.root.to_s}/}
  end
end
MiniTest.backtrace_filter = MyBacktraceFilter.new
```

The filter method accepts the full stack trace in the `bt` parameter as an array and returns the filtered array. If you want the entire stack to show simply pass the input:

```
class MyBacktraceFilter
  def filter bt
    bt
  end
end
MiniTest.backtrace_filter = MyBacktraceFilter.new
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try setting global variable $DEBUG to non-nil value. If that's minitest who filters your backtrace, setting `$DEBUG = true` would ensure that the entire backtrace is printed out.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to wrap failing code with:

```
begin
  # failing code
rescue Exception => e
  puts e.message
  puts e.backtrace
end
```

Another way is debugging your application with `ruby-debug`.